# Daily health data collection in C#

Tags: c#

I am a rookie in C# programming and I have a project due. The project was to create your daily schedule in C# ,which I did, took a long time...but it was fun. Second,something that I do not know how to do, is to create some sort of program with several buttons (buttons for averaging,summing etc.) . But the prime option of this program is to insert weight. Insert it daily and have it show by date (DD:MM:YYYY). Example : On (current date) you weighed : (your weight).

I do not even know how to start this program and how to keep the data. I mean ,after closing the program and reopening it the weights would not be gone.

I am sorry if I did not make myself clear enough and thank you for your time!!!

P.S:I do not want the whole solution to it,just some hints...Thank you.

Comment: "Just some hints" isn't really an answerable question. Can you ask a *specific* question about code you have?

Comment: A good introductory way to do this is just write the data to a file for each user before closing. Then on start up read the data from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs commonly store data in either text files (XML or JSON etc) or in a database (SQLite, MySQL, MongoDB etc). Probably a file based approach for you would be simplest. So you should create an object (class) to represent an entered date and weight combination (this is Object Oriented programming). Then create an instance of that class in response to user input, then figure out how to save the user input to your storage of choice (files or database). Later when you want to retrieve it, figure how to get the data from your storage format and back into an object, then how to display that object to the user (output it to the console, or create a [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)).

By the way, you don't want to store the date as a string. Don't make that common programming mistake. You should use the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Then when you display it to the user (or take input from the user) you can convert it to your format of choice.

Comment: Aha,i understand how I should proceed next (as I said,i am currently learning) ,thank you for the info,did not know some of the things you mentioned there. also @BradleyDotNET how should I begin making the connection between the database with my DateTime and the info I have to input? Thank you again!

Comment: In the future, if you stop and break down your issue logically, then it should make the job of figuring this out much easier. Instead of asking "where do I need to start and what should I think about" you should ask yourself "What am I trying to do, and what should I do to make that happen?". Then, if you get stuck actually doing any of that you should first perform a Google search to see what others have done. If you're still stuck and you can ask a specific question, then it's probably okay to post about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Understood. I will get back to the finding a solution...just wanted some insight. Hope i didnt waste anyones time with this. Thank you again for your hospitality.